# javascript behaviour in run time differs from debug

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have some problem debugging a script, just because in debug mode all works fine... but not in runtime:
I have this function in javascript:

```
function Add() {
    ... 
    $('#Value').val($('#Value').val()); // Value is a div class="input"
    ...
    $.get('@Url.Action("GetSomeData", "_Shared")', { id: parseInt($('#DataID').val()) },
            function (result) { $('#SomeData').val(result); });

    if ($('#SomeData').val() == "x") {
        $('#tmp').val($('#Value').val());
    }
    else {
        $('#tmp').val("0");
    }
    ...
}
```

and the controller _Shared simply returns an attribute:

```
public string GetSomeData(int id)
{
    return unitOfWork.DataRepository.GetByID(id).Something;
}
```

What happens is when I use a breakpoint in the "`if`", `$('#SomeData').val()` has the correct value but if I remove the breakpoint, write a `console.log($('#SomeData').val())` and execute, it is alway empty and the `$('#tmp').val()` is always "0".
Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Regarding the duplicate, in this case your "variable" is `$('#SomeData').val()`.

Comment: asynchronicity? ouch! this is new for me, I will explore it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a synchronicity issue. `$.get` is asynchronous, and the callback you pass it will run when it is finished, *not* inline with the code where it is written. So your `function (result) { $('#SomeData').val(result); });` is running after your `if ($('#SomeData').val() == "x") {`...

You can fix this by adding the code to run after the `$.get` to the callback:

```
$('#Value').val($('#Value').val()); // Value is a div class="input"
...
$.get('@Url.Action("GetSomeData", "_Shared")', { id: parseInt($('#DataID').val()) },
        function (result) {
            $('#SomeData').val(result);
            if ($('#SomeData').val() == "x") {
                $('#tmp').val($('#Value').val());
            }
            else {
                $('#tmp').val("0");
            }
        });

...
```

Note, it works when you add the breakpoint because that gives your asychronous `$.get` time to finish and execute.

Comment: Exactly. This is the solution I've found too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the event binding on Jquery on load event?

```
$(function(){
//Your code here
});
```

If not, maybe in the runtime, jquery had not found your element (#Value) yet, so it will return empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a workaround to this asynchronicity situation:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("GetSomeData", "_Shared")', { id: parseInt($('#DataID').val()) },
    function (result) {
        if (result == "x") {
            $('#tmp').val($('#Value').val());
        }
        else {
            $('#tmp').val("0");
        }
        $('#SomeData').val(result); 
    });
```

Testing inside the function works like a charm. Thanks for the clues.